# Installation stuck at copying files after booting

Tags: installation, wubi, windows-vista

Used windows installer to install Ubuntu in a Toshiba Qosmio F50, using windows Vista.
After rebooting, Ubuntu installation started but got stuck at roughly around 70% as it mentions "Almost finished copying files .."

What should I do?? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can try uninstalling the application from the windows side. (It should have finished installing on the windows side). Once you have done that you can download the .iso file and burn it to a cd. Boot to the cd, and choose install.

The installer will see that you have windows already, and you can choose to install side by side with windows. (this will install it the same way the windows installer does, within the windows install).

iso link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Check and make sure your file downloaded correctly with an md5 hash. You can find a list of all the hashes at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

To find out how to check the file please look at this documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, actually I initially tried booting from a DVD which I hv burned correctly, but unfortunately that was unsuccessful and whenever I boot from the DVD the system keeps writing the following:  "PXE - E61 : media test failure, check cable. PXE- MOF: exiting PXE ROM "

Comment: PXE is a network booting option built into your computer. You can disable it in the bios. However, burning the operating system to a CD should not kick that off, unless it failed in booting and PXE was the next boot. 

Why don't you redownload the iso again. Check and make sure you got a good copy by checking its md5 hash. I will edit my answer to include these instructions.